# Правильный массив

Tags: массивы, php

Хочу сделать сам зависимые списки, например,

```
$city = array ('Московская область' => array(
0=> 'Москва',
1=> 'Иваново',
...)
'Санкт-Петербург и область' => array (
    0 => 'Санкт-Петербург',
    1 => 'Александровская',
))
```

и понять для себя, как это делается!
все города у меня находятся в БД! создал функцию city(). Хочу взять вот эти города в массив через цикл, но не получается! Поможете?

```
   function city($param_1,$param_2){
        $gorod = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE relations IN ($param_1,$param_2)");

    while($mysql = mysql_fetch_array($gorod)){
        $gorod_title=$mysql['title'];
            $gorod_id=$mysql['id'];
            echo ($gorod_title).'<br />';
            $ul=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE relations='5' AND respect=$gorod_id");
        if (mysql_num_rows($ul)!=0){
                while ($ul_1=mysql_fetch_array($ul)){
   echo $ul_1['title'];

   }
    }
   $subject[]=array($gorod_id=>$gorod_title);
        }
    }

   city(3,6);
```

Comment: у вас этот код рабочий?, у меня ощущение, что данные он неверно берет :)

Comment: он берет эти данные правильно, только не в массив, а просто на вывод можно так написать! получить, эти данные я получаю, а именно как в массив не правильно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

почему просто не достать с БД название городов и не набить массив к примеру таким способом...

```
foreach($entry_array  as $key => $city) {
    $cities[] = $city; 
}

//само собой можно добавить и какое нибудь условие. Этот способ намного понятнее и удобнее + работает на порядок быстрее.
```

Comment: этот способ правильный, когда мы знаем $entry_array

Comment: Была бы возможность ответить на свой вопрос, ответил бы!))